# PHP Error Page (custom)

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I want to know if it is possible to redirect to a custom error page if there is an error.
So I have this Exception:

```
    if (empty($user['user'])) {

        throw new Exception("Failed to get the correct User", 400);
    }

}catch(DAOException $e) {
    throw new Exception($e->returnErrorMessage(), $e->returnHttpCode());
}catch(Exception $e) {
    throw new Exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
}
```

And I want to redirect it to a custom error page with the message "this activation link is incorrect".
Do I need to change something in the route or in the exception or both?
And how to do it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: there are loads of ways to do this. you could `header()` to a different location, you could literally just include a php script, many MVC frameworks automatically take you to an error controller, so it depends on your setup

Comment: Could you show me please how to inculde this in my current code?

Comment: Well, the simplest possible case would be to get rid of the exception, and replace it with `require_once 'my-error-page.php'; exit;`.

Comment: And how would my-error-page.php look like? Is there anywhere I can look? I just want a message in it with "The activation link is incorrect".

Comment: It could literally just be plain HTML, whatever you wan't in it!

Comment: And what do you mean with require_once, is that something I need to write in the code? Like this: if (empty($user['user'])) { require_once 'my-error-page.php'; exit;} How would that look like?

Comment: yes, exactly. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in 2 methods,

1. When you catch an exception, try to have the exception message in a variable and redirect to the custom error page with the errorMessage as parameter. So in the custom error page get the value using $_GET['errorMessage']
2. When you catch an exception, save it to the exception table or session. Then go to the custom error page by redirection, so you can get the message from table/session and display it in screen.

Note: 
  For redirection in PHP you can use "header()". In Javascript, you can use "window.location.href".

Comment: How can I redirect it to a custom error page, and how does a custom error page look like? I dont understand what you mean with the value

Comment: Use this code to redirect, 
<script type="text/javascript">location.href = 'yourURL';</script>

And the custom error page should look like a normal page with header, footer and error message to display in body of the page.